# AJAX Call Not Populating DropDownList

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a project built in MVC. On one of my pages a person is able to select a service from a drop down list. There are currently 3 drop down list each are dependent on the previous. Example Select: State then City and finally Service. I can get State and City to populate, but Services drop down list remains empty. So far I have went into the browser console and seen the correct information is being sent back from the server. I believe the issue is in the View, most likely the Form, but I am unable to see the issue

[image: Click to See Image]

View: AJAX Call

```
        function GetAvailableServiceAreas() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Service/GetAvailableServiceAreas",
            data: { stateId: $('#StateId').val() },
            datatype: 'JSONP',
            async: true
        })
        .done(function (serviceAreas) {
            $('#ServiceAreaId').empty();

            $.each(serviceAreas, function (i, serviceArea) {
                $("#ServiceAreaId").append(
                    $('<option/>')
                    .attr('value', this.ServiceAreaId)
                    .text(this.Name)
                );
            });

            GetServices();
        });
    }

    function GetServices() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Service/GetServices",
            data: { serviceAreaId: $('#ServiceAreaId').val() },
            dataType: "JSONP",
            async: true
        })
        .done(function (services) {
            $('#ServiceId').empty(); 

            $.each(services, function (i, service) { 
                $("#ServiceId").append(
                    $('<option/>')
                    .attr('value', this.ServiceId)
                    .text(this.Name)
                );
            });

            GetServiceDescription();
        });
    }
```

View Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RequestService", "Service", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="two-third" style="margin-right: 0;">
    <div id="requestService" style="overflow: auto">
        <h2>Request a Service</h2>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="display-label">Select a State</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select id="StateId" name="StateId">
                <option value="0">loading states...</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">Select a Service Area</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select id="ServiceAreaId" name="ServiceAreaId">
                <option value="0">loading service areas...</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">Select a Service</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select id="ServiceId" name="ServiceId">
                <option value="0">loading services...</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="selectedService" style="display: none;">
            <div class="display-label">Service Description</div>
            <div class="editor-field" id="ServiceDescription"></div>
            <div class="serviceOptions" id="ServiceOptions"></div>
            <div style="text-align: right;">
                <input type="submit" id="SubmitRequest" value="Select a Contractor" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" class="stateId" name="StateId" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" class="serviceAreaId" name="ServiceAreaId" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" class="serviceId" name="ServiceId" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" class="basePrice" name="BasePrice" value="0" />
}
```

Comment: what is the data coming back from GetServices ? You says the dataType is **JSONP**

Comment: The data coming back from "GetServices" is the ServiceId for the Name of the Service (varchar50)

Comment: Are you sure you want JSONP ? Are you doing a cross domain request ?

Comment: No I am not sure. I know within the console the request is XHR

Comment: Are you making the ajax call to same domain (app) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax call, you specify `dataType:"jsonp"`. This is typically a workaround technique when trying to access data from other domains because by default, it is not possible to do that because of Cross domain policy.

When you specify `dataType:"json"`, your server is expected to wrap the response in a call back method(which will be also send by the caller). In your case, you are sending back a collection/array of items with ServiceId and Name property. You are not handling the response for JSONP calls.

If your server side code is in the same domain, just remove the `dataType:"json"` from your ajax call parameters and it will work fine.

Comment: I appreciate you taking time out to answer my question. Your answer is the solution to my question.